# Use Firebase Notifications using Notification composer targets

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, android-notifications

I would like to use Firebase Notifications and target users by App, Version, Country, Language, etc.

Is there an API to let me send notifications using targets?

In the case of iOS I can't use the Notification Composer because I have to send the field mutable-content and/or content-available. Even when I send them on additional options they are ignored.

https://medium.com/@tsif/ios-10-rich-push-notifications-with-media-attachments-a54dc86586c2

Any other valid approach is welcome.

[image]